# How can wget download a webpage with php as plain html?

Tags: downloads, wget

I want to download a website that uses php to generate its pages. If I use

```
wget --convert-links --mirror --trust-server-names the_website.com
```

the php files are downloaded as php files. When I open the webpage locally, FF gives me a popup box asking whether I want to open the php file of a page with gedit.

Is there any way to download a full web page as plain html so that I can access them in a browser locally?

Comment: Did you try using: wget -r the_website.com :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, you can force `wget` to rename every extension to HTML on download with the `--adjust-extension`/`-E` flag:

```
wget --convert-links --mirror --trust-server-names --adjust-extension the_website.com
```

Answer (score 0):

They're not actually PHP files though, they just have PHP extensions. There's no simple fix for this. You could rename all the files to .html but then all the links would need fixing too.

The simplest way is to serve the files instead of Firefox opening them directly. You can do that by cding into the directory and then using some python magic:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

And then opening `http://localhost:8080` in your browser.

---

Again, these aren't real PHP, they're just saved in files that mirror the URL. You don't need to set up PHP and/or Apache (et al) to view them.

---

Edit: if you have PHP installed you can use PHP's built-in server:

```
 php -S localhost:8080
```

That should handle the mimetype issue, but I wouldn't bother if you don't have PHP installed.

Comment: Nice  idea, but I think this also simply serves the .php file as a download.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work.

Comment: Yeah, bloody MIME types. This can be overridden but it's a big fluffy pain in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

[Httrack](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/07/httrack-346-1-website-copier-released.html) is pretty good at downloading entire webpages as static offline-copies.

I've used it a few times with good results.

Comment: Hi mike, thanks for the suggestion. For some or other reason it did not work out of the box for me and I have no time to check. But it seems promising.